# Stop ReactJS from rendering every time this.setState() is called?

Tags: reactjs

How can I stop `<AnotherComponent/>` from rendering every time `this.setState()` get's called? Simple example below, although my app is much more complex. I have a bunch of subcomponents for a simple game, i.e. separate components to A) update the score, B) show a push button and C) show random images.

Everytime `setState()` is called it renders all the sub components, I want to STOP it from rendering at least one specific component. I'm trying to wrap my head around using `shouldComponentUpdate`, not sure if I should use this in the parent component or child:

```
var App = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
      return {
         isA: false
      };
   },

    handleClick: function() {
        this.refs.SomeComponent.myAction();
        if ( localStorage.showMsg ) {
            this.setState( {isA: true} );   
        } else {
            this.setState( {isA: false} );
        }

    },

   render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
           <SomeComponent handleClick={this.handleClick} ref="SomeComponent" />
           <AnotherComponent />
         </div>
      );
   } 
});
```

Comment: I resolved this using `shouldComponentUpdate` in the sub-component, but wondering if this is just a result of having too much state in my parent component. It has state for a social share button, tutorial text, as well as game play components (play button, random images, etc). I read that you should put all state as high as possible in the component tree, maybe I went too far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` should only be used as an optimization.  Because `render` should be a function of props and state, if react wanted to rerender everything at random intervals, your application should still behave correctly.

Comment: I am generating a random # inside my `render()` and showing different images based on the random #. My child component doesn't do anything else that could hold & update state. One option is putting the random # code in the parent component and pass it in as `Props` to the child. Another option is use `Refs` and put the rand # code in a method of the child component which calls `setState()`, then call that method via `Refs` in the parent. I prefer using State to Refs, seems easier to follow the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to stop the render? If a component's props and state haven't changed then, although it will render, the DOM will not be updated. If you have some really expensive comuptation in your `render` then you should by all means use `componentShouldUpdate`, bearing in mind the caveat from the docs:

> By default, shouldComponentUpdate always returns true to prevent
>   subtle bugs when state is mutated in place, but if you are careful to
>   always treat state as immutable and to read only from props and state
>   in render() then you can override shouldComponentUpdate with an
>   implementation that compares the old props and state to their
>   replacements.

If you're worried about top-heavy state, you should look at the [Flux pattern](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) and also [Fluxxor](http://fluxxor.com/) for a nice implementation.

Comment: how can this be achieved? shouldComponentUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps gets invoked twice, forcing the state and the props to be the same the second time around.